# Two PHP pages to pass form data to the same target file

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a Customer Details PHP page. To get to this page, the user either signs up with new details on *signup.php* or they log in on *login.php*.

Ive been told the best way to submit data and be redirected to the correct page is to use `action="details.php"` in the form, and then at the start of the *details.php* file use the values from the `$_POST` array to populate my SQL database.

However, I need to do the same sort of thing with the *login.php* code, so at the top of *details.php* there will be the code to enter the form data from *signup.php* and the verifying code from *login.php*.

Surely there is a way of doing the data submission directly from *signup.php* so there isnt two sets of PHP in the *details.php* file? If not how do i differentiate so that login only uses the login code and signup uses the submit code?

Comment: You could set a hidden field on each page called: name='referrerpage' with either value='signup' and do: if ($_POST['referrerpage']=='signup'){ do this } else{ do this }

Comment: Shouldn't the signup page's action be signup.php and login page's action be login.php, then both redirect to details.php after the post?

Comment: I agree with @Grant send a variable unique to each page along with the form and then use an if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to have PHP check for form data+possible redirect and after that form print

**Example:** (my common usage)(i merged login&signup into one file)

```
<?php
  $error = "";
  if( !empty($_POST['signup']) ){
    //do signup
    //$signup = assign true/false whether sign up was successfull or not
    if( !$signup ){ //if signup wasnt successfull generate error
      $error = "Sign up error.";    
    }    
  }
  if( !empty($_POST['login']) ){
    //do login
    //$login = assign true/false whether login was successfull or not
    if( !$login ){ //if login wasnt successfull generate error
      $error = "Log in error.";    
    }    
  }
  if( empty($error) ){
    //there were no errors
    header("Location: details.php"); //redirect to details.php
    exit(); //send nothing else!
  }
?>

<div class="error"><?php if(!empty($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($error); /*escape*/ } ?></div>

<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="signup" value="yes">
  <!-- ...some other input fields... -->
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>

<br>

<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="login" value="yes">
  <!-- ...some other input fields... -->
  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ive accepted this answer based on the fact I would like the code for submission on the same page as the form. @Grants answer below works just as well though, hence the upvote. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You could set a hidden field on each page as below:

```
<input type=hidden name='referrerpage' value='signup'>
```

AND

```
<input type=hidden name='referrerpage' value='login'>
```

and do:

```
if ($_POST['referrerpage']=='signup'){ 
     //do this 
} else{ 
     //do this
}
```

Comment: Ok that sounds perfectly logical! So is it common practice to do the submitting/verifying/etc on the page AFTER the form as suggested (ie at the start of the page redirected to)?

Comment: It just seems to me that it would be neater if the form submission code was on the same page as the form...

Comment: Giovanni - nobody says it cant be on the same page. It is even common practice to have `<?php /*test post code*/ ?> <form>Form Content</form>`